# how Invoke-command with -scriptblock {} behave in case target computer disconnected in the middle of the session

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-remoting

I'm working in an MS AD environment. I have configured WSMan and CredSSP. Everything is working fine, PSSessions work great.

We had an issue a few days ago, by mistake one of the sysadmins created a firewall rule through a GPO that blocked all Inbound connections (He meant to Allow connections). By the time he could react to the mistake, the policy had been updated on many stations.

At this point, no computer could receive any updates from the domain controllers. All of those stations were blocked from accessing anything outside.

To fix this I had to take firewall down, update the group policy, and bring the firewall back on. It worked on some portion of the computer stations.

Since then, I wrote a few scripts to handle situation like this in the future. My only concern is how `Invoke-Command -ComputerName x -ScriptBlock {} -Authentication Credssp -Credentials $cred` will behave in case of a communication breakdown between the computer executing the command and the target computers. Will the script block complete or will it stop the execution?

What would be the best alternative of sending a command to a computer and have it execute, even if networking goes down (Since taking down firewall might break communication).

Comment: Since v3 (on client and on server) PowerShell session will likely go to [disconnected state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_disconnected_sessions).

Comment: PetSerAl thx for the comment, I read the link u sent me, i want to make sure i got this right : if i add InDisconnectedSession to the invoke-command it will immediately disconnect the session and keep running the whole block of code regardless ??

Comment: Yes. Remote session will keep running the code until it hit some other restriction, like idle timeout.

Comment: thx or the comments guys, i finished my script and it went well. i have just one more question, in my environment i have some windows exp updated with PS v2 .0, since this version isn't supports disconnect state, is there any other approach that might solve this issue ? I know i can use other alternatives like PSexec but if there is any idea where PS v2 can be helpfull i will appreciate hearing it :) thanks ag ain